# What is the neutral way of telling someone to "do whatever you want"?

Tags: word-choice, connotation, nonsubjective

> Do whatever you want

This sentence can carry a negative tone (highly probable). Making it sound that someone is fed-up and/or simply doesn't care. Especially after one has had a heated discussion/argument.

How can I tell that in a manner that it carries a neutral and preferable a positive tone?

Comment: How about "The choice is yours."

Comment: "Do as you please" sounds quite polite.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Plenty of options for this one. All of the following can be made to sound snarky if said with a sarcastic tone, but none of them carry an inherent negative connotation.

> It's up to you. OR I'll leave it up to you.
>
> It's your call.
>
> I'll let you decide.
>
> Let me know what you prefer.
>
> It's up to your discretion.
>
> You're free to choose.

...and more.

The choice between these depends a little bit on context. If you're trying to convey that you want them to choose, but that you don't need a say in the choice, I'd personally choose "Let me know what you prefer," because I want to stay in the loop.

If, on the other hand, I'm trying to say "I don't care what you do" in a polite way (simply saying that I'm not affected by the choice), I'd lean toward "It's up to you."

Again, it depends on the situation, so when deciding which to use, *it's up to you.* ;)

Answer (score 8):

A neutral version would be, "As you wish." A more positive spin on it would be something along the lines of "I'm sure you will make the right decision" or "No matter what you decide, I will back you up."

Answer (score 7):

The phrase *feel free* has a fairly neutral to positive tone, as in

> Feel free to do whatever you would like.

But do bear in mind that almost *any* phrase can be negative when delivered with a good dose of sarcastic tone.

Answer (score 2):

In legal documents you might see

> "Please govern yourself accordingly."

Colloquially, you might write

> "Please act accordingly", or just "Act accordingly."

I think these are quite neutral but much more formal.

Answer (score 1):

Another neutral phrase is ["It's your call"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=it%27s%20your%20call) (or *You make the call*), about which Urban Dictionary says

> It's your decision
>
> *Nobody can make this decision for you - it's your call.
> It's your call, just say what you want.*

Answer (score 1):

How about **Proceed as you see (or think) fit**?

Oxford Dictionaries:

> [**see (or think)
>   fit**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/see_(or_think)_fit):
>   consider it correct or acceptable to do something

**Proceed as you see (or think) fit** demonstrates confidence and trust in the judgment of the other party. And it's empowering.

Answer (score 0):

***Go ahead*** is something that I hear pretty frequently these days. It mightn't be very formal, but it's not negative anyways.

From [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/go_1):

> #### **go ahead**
>
> *phrasal verb*
>
> **1** to start to do something, especially after planning it or asking
> permission to do it:
>
> - ***go ahead and do something***
>   *I went ahead and arranged the trip anyway.*
>
> 2 ...
>
> **3** *spoken* used to give someone permission to do something, or let
> them speak before you:
> *'Do you mind if I open the window?' 'No, go ahead.'*
> *If you want to leave, go right ahead.*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest considering **don't mind me**.

To tell someone to carry on with what they were doing or about to do.

[**Don't mind (someone)**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/don%27t+mind+me)

Don't interrupt what you are doing on account of someone; pay no attention to someone or their words, actions, or behaviors. (TFT)

Comment: I wanted to delete my answer, but actually I believe in some certain situations it works. So, I'm leaving the answer in case it interests anyone.